# Using batch file to start VS C# Project with params

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to start my project with some parameters.

This is working:

[image: Visual Studio Debugger]

With these settings I can do:

`string  postBox = ReadCommandArgsOrAppsettings("ExchangeMailbox");`

And it will look up in the field "Befehlszeilenargumente" (Cmd-Args)

No what I would like to do is start my .exe with a .bat File:

```
> start "Param" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ISEAG\ISESP2Exchange.exe" -ExchangeMailbox:"luca.hostettler@mail.ch";
```

But this is not working, does start the program but the ExchangeMailbox is empty and that causes my program to close and tell:

> **Error: The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.**

So how do I pass the param -ExchangeMailbox from my .bat to my .exe the right way?

Comment: It seems that the -ExchangeMailbox:"luca.hostettler@mail.ch"; is actually a parameter for the "start" command. Why are you using the "start" command in your bat instead of directly calling the ISESP2Exchange.exe program?

Comment: I have tested it as: call ISESP2Exchange.exe -ExchangeMailbox:"...." and "C:\Program Files (x86)\ISEAG\ISESP2Exchange.exe" -ExchangeMailbox:"..." both trys didn't work

Comment: start your .exe directly from Command-Line and break in main(), look at argv[]. Here you should see your arguments. This is the first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the short time I gave you :P

I was able to find out the error was in the .bat file:

I'm using now the following command:

> ```
> call "C:\Program Files (x86)\ISE AG\ISESP2Exchange\ISESP2Exchange.exe"  -ExchangeMailbox:"luca.hostettler@mail.ch" -SharepointAdditionalFilter1:"&lt;Contains&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='ParticipantsPicker'/&gt;&lt;Value Type='Text'&gt;Sindy&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Contains&gt;"
> pause
> ```

Thanks to all for commenting and bringing me to this answer :)